# Error while upgrading laravel from 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Today I decided to upgrade my app from Laravel 5.0 to 5.1. But while upgrading, I am facing the following issue:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Config\Repository::__construct() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 32 and defined in /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 23
```

Please help me. I need to get my app up and running once again. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error, and the issue was:

I created manually the files `compiled.php`, `routes.php`, `config.php`, and `services.json` inside `bootstrap/cache` folder, but those files do not need to exist, they will be generated by Laravel application.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 0):

del storage/bootstrap/cache/[files], this resovle my problem